# Deriving magnetic field energy per unit volume for a wire

Tags: energy, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

The magnetic energy per unit volume for an inductor can be derived from the formula:

$U=\frac{1}{2}L{I}^{2}$

But how to derive formula for energy per unit volume for a (long) wire. Since there is no inductance for the wire, I don't know to derive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy is located in the magnetic field $\vec{B}$ around the wire.
The [magnetic energy density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_energy) is
$$\frac{dU}{d^3r}=\frac{1}{2\mu_0}\vec{B}^2$$
with the magnetic field given by
$$B(r)=\frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi r}.$$

Then you can calculate the total energy by integrating this energy density
over the whole volume outside the wire.
I recommend using cylindrical coordinates $(r,\phi,z)$ to make the calculation easier.

$$\begin{align}
U&=\iiint \frac{1}{2\mu_0}\vec{B}^2 d^3r \\
 &=\int_0^\ell \int_0^{2\pi} \int_R^\infty \frac{1}{2\mu_0}\left(\frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi r}\right)^2 r\ dr\ d\phi\ dz \\
 &=\ ...
\end{align}$$
You should end up with an expression
proportional to the squared current $I^2$ and length $\ell$,
and somehow depending on the radius $R$ of the wire.

So actually the wire has an inductance $L$ (proportional to the length $\ell$).

Comment: "The magnetic energy density is given $\frac{dU}{d^3r}=\frac{1}{2\mu_0}\vec{B}^2$ "   Can you provide the source for that?

Comment: @AlphaDelta I have added a Wikipedia-link for that.